# Count if current row and next row meet the criteria

Tags: excel

For example, I have a table in with thousands of row:

```
      | col
row 1 | NN
row 2 | NNP
row 3 | VB
row 4 | NNP
row 5 | NN
row 6 | NNP
row 7 | JJ
row 8 | NUM
row 9 | CW
.....
row 10000 | NNP
```

Can I count with condition :
IF (row 1 = NN AND row 2= NNP) AND (row 2 = NN AND row 3= NNP) AND ... AND (row 9999 = NN and row 10000 = NNP) THEN count?

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10000="NN")*(A2:A10001="NNP"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A999,"NN",A2:A1000,"NNP")
```